# Google Cloud Platform API Creating Service Accounts by a Service account (PHP)

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to create a service account on a project using a service account but I can't get it to work. Right now I'm just simply trying to list all service accounts from a project using a service account who was permission but it returns a 401 error. Is this even possible to do with a service account?

```
    $sa = new ServiceAccountCredentials([
        'iam.serviceAccounts.list'
    ], base_path() . '/credentials.json');

    $middleware = new AuthTokenMiddleware($sa);
    $stack = HandlerStack::create();
    $stack->push($middleware);

    // create the HTTP client
    $client = new Client([
        'handler' => $stack,
        'base_uri' => 'https://iam.googleapis.com',
        'auth' => 'google_auth'  // authorize all requests
    ]);

    $response = $client->get('v1/projects/project-id-1/serviceAccounts');
    var_dump((String) $response->getBody());
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Edit:
My packages:

```
"google/auth": "^1.19",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1"
```

Comment: You can use service accounts to create resources (for example, create other service accounts), and similar to the operations that you are able to execute from the console, the service account should be authenticated, and should have the adequate permissions.

Can you review and follow the steps described in [Authenticating as a service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production), and for the adequate permissions, review and follow [Creating and managing service accounts - Required roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#permissions).

Answer (score 3):

The second line of your code **'iam.serviceAccounts.list'** is incorrect. You are specifying an IAM permission. The method requires a **scope**.

Refer to the [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-auth-library-php/main/Google/Auth/Credentials/ServiceAccountCredentials.html) for this method.

```
$sa = new ServiceAccountCredentials([
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
], base_path() . '/credentials.json');
```

With your second parameters, when the method is called, a lookup of the requested scope is performed. Since you did not specify a valid scope, the end result is you have a credential with **no permissions**. That causes the error message:

```
Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token ...
```

Do not control permissions via scopes when using service accounts. Use IAM roles to define which permissions a service account has. Then use the **cloud-platorm** scope.

I wrote an article on Google Cloud credentials and PHP that might help with details:

[Google Cloud Application Default Credentials – PHP](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-application-default-credentials-php/)